# If $p=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdots=\prod_{n=1}^\infty2$ then $p=0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I started with

$$p=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdots=\prod_{n=1}^\infty2$$
(Product Sum up to infinity)
$$p=2*p$$

Only $0$ is the number which satisfies the above equation.
Is that mean $p=0$

If it then Why?

Comment: $\infty$ also verifies this.

Comment: This infinite product is divergent to $\infty$

Comment: Since the product does not converge, you aren't really justified in treating it as a number.

Comment: You can also say that the product doesn't satisfy the condition for convergence of infinite products, that is, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$, but since products that converge to $0$ are treated as divergent, you don't really get that much out of it.

Comment: Taking infinite product of numbers can move the result outside the original set of numbers. Over real numbers, the infinite product of $2$ diverges. In the case when such a product converges, the limit will be $0$. e.g. the infinite product of $2$ converges to $0$ as [2-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Answer (score 1):

$p$ can't be a real number.

It is unbounded.$$\lim_{n \to \infty}2^n = \infty$$

In fact, given $M>0$, for any $n \ge \max(\lceil \log_2 M\rceil,1)$,

$$2^n \ge 2^{\max(\lceil \log_2 M\rceil,1)}\ge 2^{\log_2 M}=M$$